# How to find first and last row of a group

Tags: vba, excel

Below is an extract of my Excel data

```
A   20160101
A   20160104
A   20160105
A   20160106
A   20160107
AA  20160108
AA  20160111
AA  20160112
AA  20160113
AA  20160114
AA  20160115
AA  20160118
AB  20160119
AB  20160120
AB  20160121
AB  20160122
AB  20160125
AB  20160126
AB  20160127
AB  20160128
```

like  I HAVE over 10,000+ rows

I am trying to print name , first date , last date for each group eg

```
a  20160101 20160107   
aa 20160108 20160118
ab 20160119 20160128
```

My code

```
Sub stock_1():
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    for i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
            Set MyRange = Range("a" & i)
            LastRow_1 = MyRange.Row + MyRange.Rows.Count - 1
            firstRow = MyRange.row
end sub
```

I am getting last row of each group , but not getting first row of each group.
Please check and advise

Comment: The first column of a group is the next after the last column you found?

Comment: sorry , i need first and last row of each group

Comment: @user1592147 You can achieve it without VBA coding. Only formula can do it. If you are interested with formula only then let me know by commenting here.

Comment: You may be able to use a pivot table too.

Answer (score 1):

The trick when you are deleting/adding rows is, that you need to start looping from the end (last row to first row), because otherwise adding/deleting rows changes the row count, your loop counts wrong.

Here is something how it could work:

It starts looping backwards from the end `lRow` to the beginning `fRow`. It remembers the value `lVal` of that row and deletes consecutive rows until the value in column A changes, then it writes `lVal` into column C, remembers the next `lVal` and proceeds.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CombineConsecutiveValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better define the workbook ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lRow As Long 'find last row
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lVal As Variant 'remember last value (stop value)
    lVal = ws.Cells(lRow, "B").Value

    Const fRow As Long = 2 'define first data row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lRow To fRow Step -1 'loop from last row to first row backwards

       If i <> fRow Then 'if we are on the first row there is no value before
            If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, "A").Value Then 'if current value is same as one before
                ws.Rows(i).Delete 'delete current row
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = lVal 'write stop value in column B
                lVal = ws.Cells(i - 1, "B").Value 'remember next new stop value
            End If
       Else
            ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = lVal 'write stop value in column B (on first row)
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you could expolit dictionaries:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim vals As Variant
    Dim iVal As Long

    vals = Application.Transpose(Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value)

    With New Scripting.Dictionary
        For iVal = 1 To UBound(vals)
            .Item(vals(iVal)) = iVal
        Next

        Range("A1").Offset(0, 2).Resize(, 3) = Array(.Keys(0), Range("B1"), Range("B1").Offset(.Item(.Keys(0)) - 1))
        For iVal = 1 To UBound(.Keys)
            Range("A1").Offset(iVal, 2).Resize(, 3) = Array(.Keys(iVal), Range("B1").Offset(IIf(iVal = 0, 0, .Item(.Keys(iVal - 1)))), Range("B1").Offset(.Item(.Keys(iVal)) - 1))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

just add reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library (in VBA IDE click Tools-> References -> scroll listbox and choose "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" -> click OK)

actually such an approach speeds it all quite up since:

- avoid `IF-Then-Else` blocks
- limit range accesses by using arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here's modified version of your code (use `ption Explicit` and declre all of your variables!)

```
Option Explicit
Sub stock_1()
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, StartDate As String, EndDate As String, CellValue As String, Letters As String

    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    CellValue = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Letters = Left(CellValue, InStr(1, CellValue, " ") - 1)
    StartDate = Right(CellValue, Len(CellValue) - InStr(1, CellValue, " ") + 1)

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        CellValue = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Letters <> Left(CellValue, InStr(1, CellValue, " ") - 1) Then
            Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = Letters
            Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = StartDate
            Cells(i - 1, 4).Value = EndDate
            StartDate = Right(CellValue, Len(CellValue) - InStr(1, CellValue, " ") + 1)
        Else
            EndDate = Right(CellValue, Len(CellValue) - InStr(1, CellValue, " ") + 1)
        End If
        Letters = Left(CellValue, InStr(1, CellValue, " ") - 1)
    Next

    Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = Letters
    Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = StartDate
    Cells(i - 1, 4).Value = EndDate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a           As Variant
Dim r           As Range
Dim i           As Long
Dim s           As Long
Dim k           As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        a = .Value: s = 1

        For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a) - 1
            If a(i, 1) <> a(i + 1, 1) Then
                Set r = .Range("A" & s).Resize(i - s + 1)

                k = k + 1
                .Range("D" & k).Value = r(1).Value
                .Range("E" & k).Value = r(1).Offset(, 1).Value
                .Range("F" & k).Value = r(r.Rows.Count).Offset(, 1).Value

                s = i + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read the data into an array and then put the desired values into a dictionary like that

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
Dim rg As Range
Dim vDat As Variant
Dim i As Long, nextIndex As Long, prevIndex As Long
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set rg = Range("A1:B20")
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    vDat = rg
    nextIndex = LBound(vDat) + 1
    prevIndex = LBound(vDat) - 1

    For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)

        If i = LBound(vDat) Then
            dict.Add vDat(i, 1), vDat(i, 2)
        End If
        If nextIndex <= UBound(vDat) Then
            If vDat(nextIndex, 1) = vDat(i, 1) Then
            Else
                dict(vDat(i, 1)) = dict(vDat(i, 1)) & ";" & vDat(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
        If prevIndex >= LBound(vDat) Then
            If vDat(prevIndex, 1) = vDat(i, 1) Then
            Else
                dict.Add vDat(i, 1), vDat(i, 2)
            End If
        End If

        If nextIndex > UBound(vDat) Then
            dict(vDat(i, 1)) = dict(vDat(i, 1)) & ";" & vDat(i, 2)
            'Exit For
        End If

        nextIndex = nextIndex + 1
        prevIndex = prevIndex + 1
    Next i

    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print key, dict(key)
    Next key

End Sub
```